# How to use java.time.ZonedDateTime to generate a primitive long value in UTC

Tags: java, performance, coding-style, utc, type-conversion

What is a fairly efficient but most importantly a clean and concise way of generating a UTC timestamp as a long value (java primitive type).

I only need this to be accurate to the most precise millisecond value.

I would prefer to use java.time.ZonedDateTime as it is a clean way of obtaining a UTC timestamp and does not require any external date libraries like Joda or Apache which I do not want to use.

The 19 digits comprising the primitive long value will be broken down (formatted) as follows with an example:

```
2015  - 4 digit year with range 1000 - 9223. 
      - no zero padding allowed to ensure length is always 
        a 19 digit long value
      - 1000 is the minimum value of a four digit year 
      - 9223 is the maximum value based on first four digits 
        of Long.MAX_VALUE or 9223372036854775807

01    - 2 digit month with range 01 - 12
      - zero padded to ensure 2 digits always
      - jan is 01 and dec is 12

20    - 2 digit day with range 01 - 31
      - zero padded to ensure 2 digits always

07    - 2 digit hour with range 00 - 23
      - zero padded to ensure 2 digits always
      - uses a 24 hour clock  
      - 00 is 12 AM while 23 is 11 PM

00    - 2 digit minute with range 00 - 59
      - zero padded to ensure 2 digits always

00    - 2 digit second with range 00 - 59
      - zero padded to ensure 2 digits always

999   - 3 digit milliseconds with range 000 - 999
      - zero padded to ensure 3 digits always

99    - only 2 digits left over from primitive long. Ignore these as they 
        will be used internally as specialized counters within my program
```

My starting point is to use the following:

```
ZonedDateTime value = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ZonedDateTime value = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(value.get(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND));

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
long time = Long.parseLong(formatter.format(value)) * 100;
System.out.println(time);
```

Comment: Exactly what I want. I will make use of the last two digits so will remove the multiplication part at the end but this is just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Constantin The multiplication part is what gives you the two extra digits. Simply add your two digit number to the `long`. Addition will replace the `00` produced by the "* 100".